# What is the best windows equivalent for /tmp?

Tags: java, windows, unix

I want to improve the *cross platform behavior* of a java application. However, its test suite currently assumes the existence of the `/tmp` directory.

What is the best equivalent location on the windows platform? N.B. I most definitely do not want to assume the user has admin rights but I do want it to work on at least XP, Vista & Windows7.

Is there an existing **environment variable** that would help, and/or a set of preferred locations I could try in order of preference?

Comment: @"What is the best equivalent location on the windows platform?" -- check under 'My Computer'\Properties\Advanced\Environment Variables for both system and user-specific environment variables; typically 'temp folders' are located within the Local Settings for the current user; older versions of Windows often defaulted this to a Temp folder under Windows; I personally always redirect these folders to "C:\Temp" so I can effect easy cleanup

Comment: oxbow_lakes basically answered the question I _should_ have asked. 

Another developer had hard coded the path to the tmp directory in the test suite such that it wouldn't run on windows - it could neither write nor subsequently seach and read back the test data. 

I was looking for how to change things so that the tests would run on any platform without making assumptions about the tmp directory location.

java.io.tmpdir should do the trick.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The system property **`java.io.tmpdir`** can be used for the user's temp directory:

```
File tmp = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
```

This may be preferred over `File.createTempFile` (which, in any case, uses the `tmpdir` system property under the hood) in the instance where you want to *search* for temp files (for example, cached data from a previous invocation of your application, which sounds like it might be the case from your question).

You can change the value of the system property by providing a runtime override on the command line (a `JVM` argument): `-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\foo\bar`

**Note:** the ["trailing slash" issue descibed in the comments to *seth*'s answer below](http://rationalpi.wordpress.com/2007/01/26/javaiotmpdir-inconsitency/) can be avoided by using the relevant `File` constructor:

```
String fileName = "foobar.txt"
String tmpPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
File tmpFile;
tmpFile = new File(tmpPath + File.separator + fileName); //possible problem
tmpFile = new File(new File(tmpPath), fileName); //OK!
```

Obviously windows also has an `DOS` environment variable **`%TEMP%`** which could be used from any scripts which you have

Answer (score 8):

Why not use [`java.io.File.createTempFile()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))?

Comment: He might be looking for files which have been dropped in the user's temp directory, as opposed to creating them

Comment: I love when people hard code paths and get mad at Microsoft (and other companies) when things change... Framework calls/SDKs are your friends

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - I've had problems with java.io.tmpdir http://rationalpi.wordpress.com/2007/01/26/javaiotmpdir-inconsitency/ Maybe it's changed though as it's been awhile since I used Java

Comment: The `createTempFile` methods just uses the `java.io.tmpdir` property under the hood! See `File` lines 1668-1676

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - Yes, I know that but I've had problems before with the trailing slash on different OS (like in the link I pasted) as well as accidentally over-writing files.  I just found it safer to use createTempFile instead of using my own homegrown system.

Comment: Then use the `File` constructor taking the parent directory and file name and the problem disappears

Comment: I've modified my answer to take this into account

Comment: -1 Because the question is about the "temporal directory" and not how to create a "temporal file".  I would +1 if a could for the article cited though.

Answer (score 2):

Windows defines environment variables TEMP and TMP both giving the current user's temporary folder.

Comment: You might find that TMP exists only on machines which have developer tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.createTempFile("myPrefix","mySuffix")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insist on doing something that is windows specific you can use the `%temp%` environment variable.